# Create CoApp package with property sheets

Tags: nuget, propertysheet, nuget-spec, vsprops

I want to create a CoApp package which will just install my department's custom property sheets (currently they come from a Mercurial subrepository and we want to get rid of as many subrepositories as possible).

The property sheets reside in a a few directories:

```
- build
  - bsii.props
  - vc12
    - vc12.props
    - debug32.props
    - debug64.props
    - release32.props
    - release64.props
    - details
      - 32.props
      - 64.props
      - common.props
      - debug.props
      - release.props
```

The main property sheet is `build\bsii.props` and it has conditional imports which import the rest of the property sheets according to platform and configuration.

For the package to work correctly I need it to contain all the property sheet folder structure and to add the main property sheet `bsii.props` to the project.

I tried the following autopkg script:

```
nuget {

    nuspec {
        id = foundations.propertysheets;
        version: 4.0.0.0;
        title: Native Property Sheets;
        ...
    };

    files {
        import_props += { 
            #destination = build\native\imports\;
            ..\build\**\*.props; 
        }
    }
}
```

This indeed creates a package which contains all the required files but the property sheet is not configured for the project.

When instead I use `import_props: ..\build\bsii.props;` then the package only contains this single file, but also, it doesn't install it on the project but rather a different .props file generated by CoApp, which doesn't have a reference to my main property sheet:

```
<Import Project="..\packages\foundations.propertysheets.4.0.0.0\build\native\foundations.propertysheets.props" Condition="Exists('..\packages\foundations.propertysheets.4.0.0.0\build\native\foundations.propertysheets.props')" />
```

How do I both include all my files in the package and get the package to configure the correct property sheet on the project?

Answer (score 2):

I don't know about CoApp, but in plain nuget, If you want to add a property sheet to projects and not [import MSBuild targets and props files into project](http://docs.nuget.org/create/Creating-and-Publishing-a-Package#import-msbuild-targets-and-props-files-into-project) (the difference is when during the build it's evaluated), you can do that by putting the property sheet and the following `install.ps1` and `uninstall.ps1` scripts in the nuget package's tools/ directory.

## install.ps1

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

foreach ($config in $project.Properties.Item("Configurations").Object)
{
    $propertySheet = $config.AddPropertySheet("$toolsPath\bsii.props")
}
```

## uninstall.ps1

```
param($installPath, $toolsPath, $package, $project)

foreach ($config in $project.Properties.Item("Configurations").Object)
{
    $propertySheet = $config.AddPropertySheet("$toolsPath\bsii.props")
    $config.RemovePropertySheet($propertySheet)
}
```

See https://github.com/blole/visual-studio-builddir/tree/4ccf9bcf2d64d7ce1fd53768a9b5466c033fea46 for a complete nuget package that only installs a single property sheet.